# how to set default focus on the submit button in a popup window

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

please help me someone,,,,

i write some code to get the popup window using the following code.

```
<div id="EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_PENDING" class="popupContact" style="z-index:10003;">
                <div class="popup_textarea">
                    <h3><h:outputLabel value="#{labelMsgs.emailPendingLabel}"/></h3>
                    <div class="VerifyEmailText">
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{labelMsgs.clickToSendEmail}"/> 
                        <span class="FontItalic"><h:outputLabel value="#{headerBean.emailAddress}."/></span>
                        <br /><br />                         
                    </div>
                    <div  class="SuspendedBoxMsg">
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{labelMsgs.accountSuspend}"/><br />
                        <h3><h:outputLabel value="#{sessionScope.DASHBOARD_EMAIL_EXP_TIME}"/></h3>
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{labelMsgs.unlessYouVerify}"/>
                        <br />                                                        
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="FontWeight">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{labelMsgs.spamMailFolder}"/>
                         </span>
                        <a4j:commandLink id="resendLink" styleClass="violet_color_link" value="#{labelMsgs.regSuccSendMail}" onclick="javascript:resendLink(); this.onclick=null;" action="#{headerBean.resendEmail}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="OkButton">
                        <div class="button_input">                          
                            <a4j:commandButton id="emailConfm" styleClass="image_button" value="#{labelMsgs.okButton}" action="#{accntDashboardBean.popupRefresh}"
                                reRender="frmAccountDashboardMenu:POPUP_PANEL" oncomplete="disablePopup1('EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_PENDING', 'backgroundPopup');popupCall('#{sessionScope.toShowPopupOf}');"/>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

in this am using the id of the div to populate the popup,like this i have write some other popup code with different ids. for this i write the code in window.onload function to get the popup,
 so, i need to set the default focus on the submit button which i mentioned in the above code.

Answer (score 14):

You can set the focus to the submit button with the use of JavaScript or jQuery:

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('emailConfm').focus();
```

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/focus/):

```
$('#emailConfm').focus();
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use the following to set focus into the button

```
document.getElementById('emailConfm').focus();
```

But this may not work, to fix this I have done something like this

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('emailConfm').focus(); },100);
```

Comment: You do not need the timeout if the js code is loaded after html.

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML form tag inside your div to set focus on Submit button.
Use your input tags inside form tag, so whenever you are entering User Name or Password Submit button is always focussed on press of Enter button.

```html
<form>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="password"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `Note:- This submit button should be` ...should be what?

Comment: Not apparently if you have a select tag present.. pressing return activates selection from select.

Comment: Qualification: Not apparently if you have an "only" select tag present, in other words a select tag and a submit button.. pressing return activates selection from select. If you have an additional input  - so 1 select, 1 input and a submit - then submit button triggered.